# Accessing DiggAPI using Java

Tags: java

I am looking to know how to connect Digg API with my java code. I tried with Jigg and Digg jars but not working well. Are there any others jars available? ... Most examples are getting by php code or python. I trying to connect DIGG API with my java Desktop Application and not with my website.. Please let me know if there is any way to do this... Please let know in detail am totally confused with DIGG API Documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Google always can help you:

http://bleu.west.spy.net/~dustin/projects/digg/

Comment: HI alibm Thanks  for your reply.But i read all these things already... I don know how to apply those... Am not getting any sample program or tutorials regarding this ... Pls let me know if you found like that... Thanks ....Vijay